# IOS browser doesn't render model in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

SPA built with Vue.js that uses Forge Viewer doesn't render simple model in Ios Safari browser (iPhone XR, 13.5.1 ios, ipad). It's not the known issue with big (more than 200 mb) model crashing, the model is slim, over 16 mb. This model is rendered well in PC browsers and in browsers on Andriod devices. The version of Forge Viewer is the latest (7.24), but I also try to use older ones (7.20, 7.12). Does anyone know any solutions to start to show models on Ios devices?

The first error is 'THREE.WebGLRenderer: EXT_color_buffer_float extension not supported.'

Minimal working example on [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wilson-2s7z3?file=/src/App.vue)

[image]

Comment: Did you see any error messages show up in [Safari debug mode](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/07/12/how-to-debug-your-mobile-hybrid-app-on-ios/)?

Comment: Hello, Eason! I need time to check this out, I'll write after the mac getting in my hands.

Comment: Error "THREE.WebGLRenderer: EXT_color_buffer_float extension not supported" apprears